# Type '(err: any, data: any) => void' has no properties in common with type 'RequestInit'

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox

I'm following this example https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/timeline-animation/ to create a time based visualisation. 
I'm using this version "d3": "^5.4.0"
The code is:

```
d3.json('http://127.0.0.1:5000', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Create a month property value based on time
        // used to filter against.
        data.features = data.features.map(function (d) {
          d.properties.month = new Date(d.properties.time).getMonth();
          return d;
        });

        map.addSource('visits', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': data
        });

        map.addLayer({
          'id': 'visits-circles',
          'type': 'circle',
          'source': 'visits',
          'paint': {
            'circle-color': [
              'interpolate',
              ['linear'],
              ['get', 'name'],
              6, '#FCA107',
              8, '#7F3121'
            ],
            'circle-opacity': 0.75,
            'circle-radius': [
              'interpolate',
              ['linear'],
              ['get', 'name'],
              6, 20,
              8, 40
            ]
          }
        });

        map.addLayer({
          'id': 'visits-labels',
          'type': 'symbol',
          'source': 'visits',
          'layout': {
            'text-field': ['concat', ['to-string', ['get', 'name']], 'm'],
            'text-font': ['Open Sans Bold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
            'text-size': 12
          },
          'paint': {
            'text-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
          }
        });

        // Set filter to first month of the year
        // 0 = January
        filterBy(0);

        document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
          var month = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
          filterBy(month);
        });
```

I'm doing exactly the same thing with the URL to my data but I'm getting some error messages

> error TS2559: Type '(err: any, data: any) => void' has no properties
>   in common with type 'RequestInit' error TS2339: Property 'value' does
>   not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Does anybody have any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the necessary code. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The type information for d3 suggests a promise based interface - perhaps older versions used callbacks.

Your code follows a callback pattern:

```
d3.json('http://127.0.0.1:5000', function (err, data) {
    // Handle err

    // Use data
});
```

Here is the promise version:

```
d3.json('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
    .then((data) => {
        // Use data
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // Handle err
    });
```

## Typed Response

The `data` that you get back can be typed. Pass a type argument to the `json` method to tell it what kind of data you will get back. For example:

```
interface ResponseData {
  features: any[];
}

d3.json<ResponseData>('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
.then((data) => {
    // Use data
})
.catch((err) => {
    // Handle err
});
```

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, now I get these errors "error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'" and " error TS2339: Property 'features' does not exist on type '{}'."

Comment: I have updated the answer to demonstrate how to pass a type argument to get type information for the response data. The second part of your comment is really a new question - but the answer is probably a combination of using `this.value` along with narrow typing of your element (`getElementById` returns the wide `HTMLElement` type and you'll need to narrow it to `HTMLInputElement`). There is more on that under "Element Types" here: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/01/embracing-typescript-strict-mode/

Comment: I'm getting that error now: core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: options is invalid

Comment: That means that the Cross Origin Request, which uses the `OPTIONS` HTTP method, is not supported by the server. You need to respond to `OPTIONS` requests to allow this.

Comment: I'm getting started with typescript and all those things around, I didn't really get the idea, can you please explain me more

Comment: This one isn't TypeScript in particular - it's how The Web works. MDN have a great article on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Actually: for the request it's fine Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK so I don't really get the idea, maybe It's because I'm a beginner in web development, i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  A workaround is use

```
(d3 as any)
```

as in:

```
(d3 as any).json(options.data, (error, d) => {
```